# Can an pair of RPis sustain a 10G TCP data stream?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ethernet-port

If a steady datastream were all they were doing, could a pair of RPIs sustain a smooth 10G data connection over a direct Ethernet wire?  Crossover cable if necessary?  And if not, anyone know of an RPi-compatible or workalike which could?

Comment: 10G? as in 10 gigabit? RPI's as in Raspbbery pi 4's? no - RPI4 has a 1gigabit ethernet - USB3 on the pi can do a theoretical 5 gigabit, so, perhaps with 4x USB-Ethernet adapters you may be able to theoretically achieve 10 gigabit - unlikely though. As for Rpi compatible or workalike ... there's plenty of *fruit*Pi and *non-fruit*Pi on the market - though, I've personally not seen one with anything over 2.5 gigabit ports

Comment: *"Crossover cable if necessary?"* Those haven't been necessary for long time; most ethernet devices including all flavours of Raspberry Pi have **auto MDI-X** -- which configures a crossover if needed (meaning only one of the two connected things need have it to work).